# How do I make a <tr> behave as a fixed topbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table that displays some information with the first row being headers for the respective information.

On scrolling, let's say 100px from the top of the page, i'd like the header row to stay fixed at the top of the visible screen so that as you scroll down the table you can still see the headers.

I've tried:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(window).pageYOffset > 100 ){
        $("#resultTableHeader").css('position', 'fixed');
        $("#resultTableHeader").css('top', '70px');
        $("#resultTableHeader").css('z-index', '2');
    }
});
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Even if it did, however, make the header row fixed, If one column expanded the header row column, then pulling it out of the flow would make that column not be expanded anymore.

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT (more info):

I can guarantee that the whole page will be just the table so staying at the top of the screen for any Y co-ord past 100px would be acceptable.
When I say fixed I mean that the header row will stay pinned to the top of the VISIBLE window as you scroll down along the table.

Comment: You've not included the html, eg what's `#resultTableHeader`.  Have you tried using `<thead>` and `<tbody>` then make the tbody scrollable?   You mention "fixed at the top of the screen" then "scroll down the table" - which aren't necessarily the same thing.  If the table is the whole screen then scrollable body will be fine and if not, then you don't want the table header stuck at the top if the table itself is no longer visible.

Comment: Your web search should be: "fixed table headers" or similar. It's ***non-trivial***. (Should it be trivial? Yes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed table header with pure html and css

```css
html, body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 37px;
  background: #500;
}
section.positioned {
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  width:800px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #333;
}
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width:100%;
}
td + td {
  border-left:1px solid #eee;
}
td, th {
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
th {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th div{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 1px solid #800;
}
th:first-child div{
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="">
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>
            Table attribute name
            <div>Table attribute name</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Value
            <div>Value</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Description
            <div>Description</div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>align</td>
          <td>left, center, right</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the alignment of a table according to surrounding text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>bgcolor</td>
          <td>rgb(x,x,x), #xxxxxx, colorname</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the background color for a table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>border</td>
          <td>1,""</td>
          <td>Specifies whether the table cells should have borders or not</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cellpadding</td>
          <td>pixels</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between the cell wall and the cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cellspacing</td>
          <td>pixels</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between cells</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>frame</td>
          <td>void, above, below, hsides, lhs, rhs, vsides, box, border</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the outside borders that should be visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>rules</td>
          <td>none, groups, rows, cols, all</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the inside borders that should be visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>summary</td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies a summary of the content of a table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>width</td>
          <td>pixels, %</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the width of a table</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @NielsSteenbeek it should be fine as long as i resize it to the window size with jquery

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem when using table elements. Most libraries use two tables to fix this. The first table only contains the th elements and the second table has all tr elements.
Check jqgrid for example.

Comment: How do you make the columns in the first table (my header) match the column sizes of my second table?

Comment: @CristianD in jqgrid they use calculation. Not that nice at all.